# The group $\mathbb{Z}^n/A\mathbb{Z}^n$ is finite iff the determinant of A is nonzero

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $n\geq 1$ and $A$ be an $n\times n$ integral matrix with columns $c_1,\ldots, c_n\in\mathbb{Z}^n$. Write $A\mathbb{Z}^n$ as the set of all integral linear combinations of the columns of A, i.e., 
$$A\mathbb{Z}^n=\{x_1c_1+\cdots+x_nc_n: x_1, \ldots, x_n\in\mathbb{Z}\}. $$
The problem is to prove that the group $G=\mathbb{Z}^n/A\mathbb{Z}^n$ is a finite group if and only if $\det(A)\neq0$, and moreover that in the case $\det(A)\neq0$, the order of $G$ is precisely $|\det(A)|$.

The case when $\det(A)$ is a unit ($\pm1$) is somewhat trivial. But how about other nonzero values for $\det(A)$? I tried to define a homomorphism  $f:\mathbb{Z}^n\to\mathbb{Z}^n, x\mapsto Ax$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}^n$, and observed that $G$ is the quotient $\mathbb{Z}^n/\operatorname{im}(f)$. How can we proceed?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the *Invariant factors theorem*?

Comment: I think [this is what you're looking for](https://ferngaston.wordpress.com/2014/08/28/calculating-the-cardinality-of-a-cokernel-using-determinants/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume first that $\det A = d \ne 0$. Using Cramer we see that $d \mathbb{Z}^n\subset A \cdot \mathbb{Z}^n$.  So $\mathbb{Z}^n/A\mathbb{Z}^n$ is of order at most $d^n$.

Assume $\det A =0$. Then there exists $r\in \mathbb{Z}^n$, $r\ne 0$, such that $r^t\cdot A=0$. Consider the map $\mathbb{Z}^n\to \mathbb{Z}$, $c\mapsto r^t\cdot c$. The map has infinite image and the kernel of the map contains $A\mathbb{Z}^n$. We conclude that $\mathbb{Z}^n/A\mathbb{Z}^n$ is infinite.

Obs: In fact one can show that if $\det A\ne 0$ then the order of $\mathbb{Z}^n/A\mathbb{Z}^n$ is $|d|$.  We can show this with geometry as follows:

Consider the lattice $L= A\mathbb{Z}^n$ inside the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Consider a basis $c_1$, $\ldots$, $c_n$ of $L$. The volume of the parallelotope  $P$ consisting of $ \sum t_i c_i$, with $0\le t_i< 1$ equals on one hand  $|\det A|$, on the other hand it equals the limit 
$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{a_N}{N^n}$$
where $a_N$ is the cardinality of $P \cap \frac{1}{N}\mathbb{Z}^n$. However, 
$a_N$ also equals the cardinality of $N P \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$, and this equals 
the order of $\mathbb{Z}^n/N L$. Therefore we have 
$$|\det A |= \lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{|\mathbb{Z}^n/N L|}{N^n}=\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{|\mathbb{Z}^n/N L|}{|\mathbb{Z}^n/N\mathbb{Z}^n|}=\lim |N\mathbb{Z}^n/NL|=\lim |\mathbb{Z}^n/L|= |\mathbb{Z^n}/L|$$

Answer (score 4):

The volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the columns of $A$ has volume $|\det A|$ and contains exactly one representative of each coset. Thus the vloume is *approximately* the combined volume of the unit cubes cntered at these representatives. The approximation gets (reletively) better if you take a large number of copies of the epiped...

And of course, $\det A=0$ means that the column vectors do not span the full space, henc ewe find a lattice point iutside o f the span; this has infinite order also in the quotient.

Comment: I think if you take parallelepipedons with unit volume, parallel to the columns of $A$, you'll cover the whole parallelepipedon.

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form), which is an algorithmic procedure for writing $A=PDQ$, where $P,Q,D$ are integer matrices, $P,Q$ invertible, and $D$ diagonal. It follows that $|\det(A)|=|\det(D)|$ and $\mathbb{Z}^n/A\mathbb{Z}^n \cong \mathbb{Z}^n/D\mathbb{Z}^n$.

I'd love to see an elementary proof along the lines below. I wish I could make that argument work better.

Let $E$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb Z^n$. Let $V$ be the image of $E$ under $A$. Then $V=AE$ and $\text{adj}(A) V = \text{adj}(A)AE = \det(A)IE=\det(A)E$ and so $\det(A)E \subseteq A\mathbb{Z}^n$. Therefore, if $\det(A)\ne0$, then $\mathbb{Z}^n/A\mathbb{Z}^n$ is finite and has size at most $|\det(A)|^n$.